Did John Wheeler retract himself on the participatory universe claims?
John Wheelers had a period where he made philosophical claims about metaphysics involving reality and consciousness.
I think he changed his mind on several of these topics through his life so I was wondering if any experts on his life here could throw any details on if he changed his mind on the participatory universe theory or how specific theory of his evolved with his though.

Not exactly. In late years, Wheeler did not go back on observer participancy, but was agonizing over reconciling it with shared reality for different observers. That led him to some doubts about the role of consciousness, but not over the informational underpinnings of the universe folded into "it from bit", questions/answers "building" the spacetime. One late publication is his chapter Information, Physics, Quantum in a 2002 book (he died in 2008 at age 97). Quanta Magazine has an informative review of Wheeler's evolution on the subject:

"At first, Wheeler thought that observer-participancy involved consciousness. After all, tables and chairs don’t make choices about what to measure; conscious observers do. But that was of no help. He saw no way to link the private experiences of individual minds into a single, shared reality.  
“On few issues in my life have I ever been more at sea than I am now on the relative weight of the individual and the collectivity in giving ‘meaning’ to existence,” he wrote. He remained at sea a few years later: “‘Consciousness’ seems to appertain to the individual. For my money the relevant concept should be a community property.” But what? In a participatory universe, one observer can ask a question and get an answer in response, and another observer can come along — tomorrow, next week, a billion years from now — and ask a different, incompatible question and get a different, incompatible answer. The universe can be shaped and reshaped in 10,000 ways by 10,000 tinsmiths, and nothing in the quantum formalism guarantees that they’ll ever agree.   Wheeler was distraught. For years, for pages, he obsessed. “I am not proud. I will confess all errors. I will try anything to crack the mystery.” After all, he wrote, “I owe it to the community to give my very best.” Any reality in which a thought, perception, or measurement outcome was someone’s private property was not a reality he could live in. At the same time, he couldn’t go back on a participatory universe. He couldn’t go back on pregeometry. “Is there any point partway between all and none on this issue?” he wondered. “Each of us a private universe? Preposterous! Each of us see the same universe? Also preposterous!” So he was stuck. And he was running out of time... The last entry Wheeler ever wrote was in 2006, age 95, nearing death, his life now bookended by questions­. It consisted of a single sentence, left behind for the community: “Hope produces space and time?”"

